# 「なお」は「ですから」という意味を含みますか？

Tags: meaning, words, word-usage

文章（書き言葉に使う）で自分の考えを陳述する場合に、

例：

```
Aがよくないですから、Bにすると思います。
Aがよくないです、なお、Bにすると思います。
```

この二つは同じ意味でしょうか？`なお`は因果関係が表現できますか？

Comment: （意味ではなく、形のことですが、）「から」は接続助詞で、「節+から+節」（「～ですから～」）と書けますが、「なお」は（副詞または）接続詞で、「文。なお、文。」（「～です。なお、～。」）と書きます

Answer (score 1, accepted):

小学館の「国語大辞典」によりますと、「尚{なお}」は「ですから」の意味でなく、むしろ「それに」の意味です。

以下の文章を辞典の定義から引用します。

> 〔接続〕一つの話を終えたあとに、追加して別の話を始めようとするときの、つなぎのことば。それに加えて。